# Perl program taking the latest login

Tags: perl

I have a log file in the log.txt file, I want to sort the username with the latest login

Example- 
        If the user PAUL has 2 logins for January and one login for February it should take 
        the  February login details( as last login for PAUL)

INPUT FILE: log.txt--

```
Administrator-25/02/2013
Administrator-26/03/2013
```

OUTPUT FILE-

```
Administrator-26/03/2013
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [perl program taking the latest login for all users](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16273185/perl-program-taking-the-latest-login-for-all-users)

Comment: So this is a log file, where entries are appended as they happen? Is there any reason to suspect that entries do not come in date order? In other words, is there any reason the last entry would not be the most recent?

Comment: Although this question is closely related to the one referenced as a possible duplicate, the other is closed and deleted, so it is not a good 'exact duplicate' at all.  The question is rather simple, especially as the file being analyzed appears to be a regular log file that will contain the latest entry for a given as the last entry for said user, so all that's needed is to read the entries, and keep the latest record for each each user.

Answer (score 1):

If you can convert the date to the ISO format, you can use simple string comparison on it. See [xkcd on ISO 8601](http://xkcd.com/1179/).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

sub later {
    my @dates = @_;
    for my $date (@dates) {
        $date = join '/', (split m(/), $date)[2, 1, 0]; # Fix StackOverflow's syntax highlighting: /
    }
    return $dates[0] lt $dates[1];
}

my @lines = qw(Administrator-25/02/2013
               Administrator-26/03/2013
               Guest-01/01/2012
               Administrator-01/01/2012
             );

my $user = 'Administrator';
my $last = q();

for my $line (@lines) {
    next unless 0 == index $line, "$user-";
    my $date = (split /-/, $line, 2)[1];
    $last = $date if later($last, $date)
}

print "$last\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

As a slightly overlong one liner

```
perl -F\- -l -a -n -e ' $d=join(q(/),reverse split(q(/), $F[1])); $l{$F[0]}=$d if (!exists($l{$F[0]}) || $l{$F[0]} lt $d); END{ for (sort keys(%l)) { $v=$l{$_}; print "$_-",$l{$_} }}' logfile.txt
```

Autosplit on - and populate a hash based on the largest date

The output is in "reverse" date order as that's what I used to compare

Answer (score 0):

Comparing date using Unix time:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use POSIX qw(mktime);
$\="\n";

open my $fh, '<','log.txt' or die $!;
my %h1;
while(<$fh>){
        chomp;
        my ($user,$date,$mon,$year)=split(/[\/-]/);  #Split record 
        my $tm=mktime(0,0,0,$date,$mon-1,$year-1900); # Calculate the epoch
        if (!exists$h1{$user} or ($h1{$user}<$tm)){  # store the bigger value in hash with the use as the key
                $h1{$user}=$tm;
        }
}
# Sort the hash on the basis of the key and print it
foreach my $k (sort keys%h1){
        my @val=localtime($h1{$k});

        $val[4]+=1;
        $val[5]+=1900;
        print $k,'-',join "/",@val[3..5];
}
```

Input file(log.txt):

```
Administrator-25/02/2013
Administrator-26/03/2013
Administrator-27/02/2013
xyz-31/01/2013
xyz-31/03/2013
```

On running the script:

```
xyz-31/3/2013
Administrator-26/3/2013
```

Comment: Thank u so much..now how do i sort the output entries based  on the alphabetical order.

Comment: I cannot understand some statements in the code,can u comment the lines in the program....